# How can i get a list of the names of all files with a size less than 70MB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\", "*.avi");
        public static string filetoupload;
        int count = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileEntries.Length > 0)
            {
                filetoupload = fileEntries[count];
                count += 1;
            }
        }

        private void FilesSizes()
        {
            string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
            double len = new FileInfo(filetoupload).Length;
            int order = 0;
            while (len >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
            {
                order++;
                len = len / 1024;
            }
            string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);
        }
```

Now fileEntries contain all the avi files.
But i want it to contain only avi files that are not above 70MB using the FilesSizes method.

I tried this way but getting error:

```
private void FilesSizes()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileEntries.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
                double len = new FileInfo(fileEntries[i]).Length;
                int order = 0;
                while (len >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
                {
                    order++;
                    len = len / 1024;
                }
                string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);

                if (len > 70)
                    fileEntries[i].Remove(i);
            }
        }
```

First i'm not sure if doing if (len > 70) is the right way to check if file size is bigger then 70MB.

Second the error i'm getting on this line:

```
fileEntries[i].Remove(i);
```

The problem is for example when i = 14 :
startIndex must be less than length of string

I tried now also returning a List

```
private List<string> FilesSizes()
        {
            List<string> filestoremove = null;
            foreach(string item in fileEntries)
            {
                string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
                double len = new FileInfo(item).Length;
                int order = 0;
                while (len >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
                {
                    order++;
                    len = len / 1024;
                }
                string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);

                if (len > 70)
                {
                    filestoremove = new List<string>(fileEntries);
                    filestoremove.Remove(item);
                }

            }

            return filestoremove;
        }
```

But for some reason it's removing only one file from the List and there are 22 files and more then one is over 100MB so i did something wrong.

Comment: Your new code is doing a lot it doesn't have to do, can't you just convert 70MB to bytes and check against the `FileInfo`'s [`.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: `List<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\").GetFiles("*.avi").Where(f => f.Length <= 70 * 1024 * 1024).ToList();`

Comment: @Loathing this should be an answer, to be more useful for other users too:)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to modify the `FilesSizes` method so that it returns the file size. Then in the button click, you could loop through the `fileEntries` array and find the file size for each entry. If the file size is appropriate, then you can do something with it: add to a new array (or better yet, `List<string>`) or append to another string.

You can make this more elegant by using Linq to query the file system. An interesting example is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546154.aspx.

Once you try something, if you need more help then just post your code.